# Performing tasks on input given by entry and updating label constantly

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

So im a little new to tkinter and was making a gui. one of the problems i was having was that when i got a value from a entry widget. i could not get the labels that were associated with that entry widget to update after i had done some arithmetic to it. for example

```
var = tk.StringVar
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = var)
entry1.pack()
then do something with var
label1 = tk.Label(root, text = var)
label1.pack()
```

i looked around before asking this and what i found was to connect the variables. i tried that but it still would  not update after the first time.

How would i get the label to update everytime a new value was entered in entry. like if 2 was entered 4 would be displayed. then if i entered 5 then the label should update automatically and 10 should be dislplayed. in this case im just multiplying by two. the label should update until i close the program.

Thanks was having alot of trouble figuring this out any help is appreciated

Comment: To link the label with the entry, use `textvariable=var` instead of `text=var` when initializing `label1`.  However, this kind of linking does not fit your request as the label just show what you input in the entry without any processing.  Better using `entry1.bind(...)` to bind the `Return` key to call a function which processes the entry and then update the label text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def enter_hit(event):
    do_something_with(var.get())

var = tk.StringVar
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = var)
entry1.pack()
label1 = tk.Label(root, text = var)
label1.pack()
entry1.bind("<Return>",enter_hit)
```

When you hit Enter on `entry1`, then it calls enter_hit. Then `var` and it's text can be gotten, and you can do what you want with it to affect `label1`.

If this doesn't suit you, and you want it to change the moment a character is inputted, then try trace.

```
def traced_event(event):
    do_something_with(var.get())

var = tk.StringVar
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = var)
entry1.pack()
label1 = tk.Label(root, text = var)
label1.pack()
var.trace("w", traced_event)
```

Comment: ohh alright thanks i was trying to figure this out but could never get what i wanted. This is pretty close ill just have to rewrite some code.

Comment: Don't forget @doge that you need to have the variable `event` there so that the info passed on has a place to go, or an error will occur.